# MixPanel Push Notification Not Received

Tags: android, push-notification, mixpanel, segment-analytics

I Have setup all the things on MiXPanel console that is mention on [MixPanel Push Notification Documentation](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android-push-notifications). I just wasted my 2 days by finding needfull on google and also on MixPanel Docs.

**Here is my Code**

```
private void initMixPanelForPush() {
    try
    {
        MixpanelAPI mMixpanel = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(this, ConstantsLib.MIXPANEL_PROJECT_ID_TOKEN);
        MixpanelAPI.People people = mMixpanel.getPeople();
        people.initPushHandling(ConstantsLib.PROJECT_NUMBER);
        people.identify(AppSharedPrefs.getInstance(context).getUserId());
        people.setPushRegistrationId(AppSharedPrefs.getInstance(context).getDeviceToken());
        people.showNotificationIfAvailable(this);
        AppController.getInstance().getAnalyticInstance().getAnalyticsContext().putDeviceToken(AppSharedPrefs.getInstance(context).getDeviceToken());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Variable I have used:

- MIXPANEL_PROJECT_ID_TOKEN: I obtained it from mixPanel ProjectSetting->Management->Token.
- PROJECT_NUMBER: project_number from **google-service.json** file

---

Registering Receiver for getting push notification.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.GCMReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="my_package _name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Sending Identity to segment**. (Device token is added here)

```
Traits traits = new Traits();
traits.putName(basicDetails.getFullName());
traits.putEmail(basicDetails.getContactEmail());
traits.putPhone(basicDetails.getContactNumber());
        traits.putValue("userId", basicDetails.getUserId());
        traits.putValue("android_devices", AppSharedPrefs.getInstance(context).getDeviceToken());
getAnalyticInstance().identify(AppSharedPrefs.getInstance(this).getUserId(), traits, null);
```

I am sending push from MixPanel by selecting users, but not getting on device.

Please let me know if somewhere I mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, now I am getting push from MixPanel:

I have just remove un-necessary methods call in the method(initMixPanelForPush)

**Updated method is**

```
private void initMixPanelForPush() {
    try
    {
        MixpanelAPI mMixpanel = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(this, ConstantsLib.MIXPANEL_PROJECT_ID_TOKEN);
        mMixpanel.identify(AppSharedPrefs.getInstance(context).getUserId());

        mMixpanel.getPeople().identify(AppSharedPrefs.getInstance(context).getUserId());
        mMixpanel.getPeople().initPushHandling(ConstantsLib.PROJECT_NUMBER);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope it will help others if they are getting same issue.